# Avoid repeating queries in several SerializeMethodFields using Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to optimize database queries in my DRF app. To do that I'm trying to avoid repeating queries in my serializers.

Supose I have a ModelSerializer like this:

```py
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genres = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    out_of_stock = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    price = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'genres', 'out_of_stock', 'price']

    def get_genres(self, obj):
        # Complex query here ...
        location_id = self.context['request'].query_params.get('location', None
        qs = Book.objects.annotate(min_price=Min('price')).filter(
                (Q(supplier__location_id=location_id) | Q(supplier_id__isnull=True)) & Q(name__in=collection_names),
                min_price__lte=F('price')).order_by()
        genres_ids = qs.filter(is_out_of_stock=False).values_list('genres__id', flat=True)
        genres = Genre.objects.filter(id__in=genres_ids)
        return GenreSerializer(genres, many=True).data

    def get_is_out_of_stock(self, obj):
        # Same complex query here ...
        location_id = self.context['request'].query_params.get('location', None
        qs = Book.objects.annotate(min_price=Min('price')).filter(
                (Q(supplier__location_id=location_id) | Q(supplier_id__isnull=True)) &
                Q(out_of_stock=False) & Q(name__in=collection_names),
                min_price__lte=F('price')).order_by()
        return qs.filter(is_out_of_stock=True).exists()

    def get_price(self, obj):
        # Another same complex query here ...
        location_id = self.context['request'].query_params.get('location', None
        qs = Book.objects.annotate(min_price=Min('price')).filter(
                (Q(supplier__location_id=location_id) | Q(supplier_id__isnull=True)) &
                Q(out_of_stock=False) & Q(name__in=collection_names),
                min_price__lte=F('price')).order_by()
        ........
        ........
        return ......
```

As you can see I need to pass some query_params to filter the queryset. Do you know what could I do to avoid repeating each query to retrieve all the serializer fields?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about passing the queryset in context?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @bdbd! In that case, where should I get the queryset and how should I pass it to the different serializermethods fields?

Comment: It would go like: `serializer = BookSerializer(context={'book_qs': <your queryset>})`, and then using it in your serializer method fields from `self`: `self.context['book_qs']`

Comment: I think it could work! I will try right now. Thanks a lot.